# Extract text in html tables if it contains certain words

Tags: python

Pyhton beginner here. Probably there is a command I am not aware of but cannot find a solution on the web.
I have a html file in string format in my Python setup.
The file looks like

```
<table>
This is Table 1
</table>

<table>
This is Table 2
</table>

<table>
This is Table 3
</table>
```

I want to extract the text between  and , but only if it matches some strings in the table. So, I only want the table that says Table 2.

I tried splitting the document on table but that became messy because it also included parts between `</table> and <table>`. I know the command re.search, but do not know how to combine it with if statements.

```py
re.search(<table>(.*)</table>
```

Comment: use `beautifulsoup` to read html

Comment: You could split the document yourself by checking sub-strings with a length of 7.  For each character in the document see if it is the beginning of `"<table>"`.  If so check what is after `"<table>"` and before next `"</table>"` else move to next character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use lxml parser to solve this issue.

```
from lxml import html

text = '''<table>This is Table 1</table>

<table>This is Table 2</table>

<table>This is Table 3</table>'''

parser = html.fromstring(text)
parser.xpath("//table[contains(text(), 'Table 2')]/text()")
```

output will be look like this

```
['This is Table 2']
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much. Do you know whether it is possible to include multiple strings in addition to Table 2?

Comment: Yes, You can use " or " condition for including multiple strings

Answer (score 0):

so one idea would be to get the html via [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Then you can simply access the tags like this:

```
row = soup.find('tr') # Extract and return first occurrence of tr
print(row)            # Print row with HTML formatting
print("=========Text Result==========")
print(row.get_text()) # Print row as text
```

Then you could get the innerHtml and compare it with your string. This would presuppose, that you can access the html with BeautifulSoup. Got this from https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/web-scraping-with-beautiful-soup